# CSplit Not Splitting

Tags: php, linux, csv

I am trying to run a complex import task that reads a CSV. This import works fine except the server runs out of available memory to finish the task. I am trying to split the files into chunks of 1000 rows to allow the server to then process these "bite size" sections one by one. My CSplit however will not split the files. Have I got my syntax right.

I have checked that the directory is correct, and that the path to the command is correct and that the file is there but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

```
function processSplit() {
      chdir('Files');
      $dir = '*';

      foreach (glob($dir) as $file) {
           system(CSPLIT_PATH . " -k -n 4 -f ' " . $file . " ' 1000 '{1000}'");

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line is incorrect.
You have:

`system(CSPLIT_PATH . " -k -n 4 -f ' " . $file . " ' 1000 '{1000}'");`

Should be:

`system(CSPLIT_PATH . " $file -k -n 4 -f ' " . $file . " ' 1000 '{1000}'");`

Besides, I would change `-f ' " . $file . " '`, for you are creating a space in front and the back of the output file.

Comment: I want also make sure - do you know that it will create files in your file system. If the files are huge, you are going to have A LOT of files being created in your file system. I would suggest rethinking your approach.

Comment: Cheers I will give that a go. Regarding your comment about re-thinking our approch, We make the files in a directory specifically intended for this. After the import all files are removed ready for the next days import. Will let you know how I get on :)

Comment: No Luck, still no split taking place.

Comment: My bad. There should be a space in front of `$file`. I mean it should be `" $file` and not `"$file`
I would also suggest changing system to echo and see what it does. Run it when you have one file only so you are not flooded with too many outputs. I will change my suggestion by adding this space.

Comment: No idea where this is going wrong like. Still not working. When I use getcwd() and echo this I get /web/*the right folder*/_cms/_cron/Products/Files/ which is correct. :(

Comment: Okay, let's try this thing. Delete, if you can, of course, all the files from that Files/ directory except one. Change `system` to `echo` and run your script. Let me see what is the output, please. If you want you can switch to chat in order to limit extended discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15971/discussion-between-grzegorz-and-shaun-hogg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Grzegorz thank you for your help, but the issue was with the structure of the file being passed and the fact that the file cannot contain any white space when using this function. Using `preg replace` to change all white space to a `_` solved the issue.